# Magento LEMP stack deployment advice

Tags: nginx, deployment, jenkins, virtualhost, magento-1.8

I've recently taken on a new role which has an existing Magento installation (1.8) that needs to be upgraded to a multi-store.

We have two LEMP stack (Linux, Nginx, MySql PHP) servers: staging and production. Updates and builds are controlled through Git and Jenkins.

We are basically planning to create and test a multi-store on the staging environment and push the changes to the production site via Jenkins Continuous Integration.

I'm new to this workflow, so I'm seeking advice on the best way to launch the new Magento multi-site.

The goal is to have: uk-site.co.uk (Current Main Website) | uk-site.co.uk (Shop) | uk-site.co.uk (Shop view)

Then: europeansite.euro-top-level-domain (Website) | europeansite.euro-top-level-domain (Shop) | europeansite.euro-top-level-domain (Shop view)

We currently have an Irish shop view and new skin working as a test. I now need to create a European website, a European shop and move the Irish shop view to be a child of the European site.

I've also created the vhost file for nginx in: /etc/nginx/conf.d/irish-site.ie.vhost

So I have a couple of questions:

Whats the safest way to deploy the Magento multi-site to production with a LEMP stack, Git and Jenkins configuration?

When I create the European website and shop, then create the European vhost files, I assume I need to repeat the process on the production site?

Do I have to change the DNS records to point to the two servers (staging and production)?

I've used a new Git repo when I created the new skin, apparently I will have to configure Jenkins to accept new ssh keys and hooks. Does that mean I will have to create the new ssh keys from my local workstation?

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated as I'm worried I may break the production site.